# About migrating magento 2.4.2-p2 to latest version

Tags: magento2

I would like to know recomendations on migration, I ant to upgrade magento 2.4.2-p2 to the latest version. But not sure if I should upgrade to magento 2.4.5-p1 2.4.5 2.4.4-p2 2.4.4-p1 2.4.4 2.4.3-p3 2.4.3-p2 2.4.3

As I notice that these new versions of magento use a more advance php version. And Im not sure if I can just skip to the latest or I need to do minor upgrades first.

Also I understand this are the commands for upgrade:

composer remove magento/product-community-edition --no-update composer require-commerce magento/product-community-edition 2.4.5-p1 --no-update --force-root-updates rm -Rf vendor composer update

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can upgrade straight forward from 2.4.2-p2 to 2.4.5-p1.

Since magento 2.4.4 requires PHP code to compatible with PHP 8.1, you might need to resolve some issues to make sure your project works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Before upgrading the version just check your 3rd party modules which all are supporting 2.4.5 version cause its just out in august. Magento 2.4.4-p1 is currently more stable and supported by 3rd party vendors.